# Getting 403 not authorized when indexing documents on Retrieve and Rank

Tags: ibm-watson, retrieve-and-rank

I am suddenly getting a 403 error when I try to POST an update to the Retrieve and Rank service.  This code is under development but it has been working up until yesterday.  The failure occurs only when doing a POST to **/v1/solr_clusters/{solr_cluster_id}/solr/{collection_name}/update**, and it fails the same way whether I do it via my program, the Swagger API documentation, or cURL.  All other operations to this service that I've tried work fine when using the same credentials that I'm using with this POST.  The error message I'm getting back is 
**Error: WRRCSH004: Service [1d111267-76b7-417a-98bd-4e9a58072ef9] is not authorized for cluster [sc262b05e8_dcf5_40b4_b662_ae85058ff07f]!**.  I don't know where the identifier (1d111267-76b7-417a-98bd-4e9a58072ef9) is coming from; that's not the userid I'm sending in.

Comment: This question is better asked on IBM's support page at https://developer.ibm.com/answers/.

Disclosure: I am an evangelist for IBM Watson.

Comment: do you still have this issue?

Comment: Actually, now it's giving me **_500 Error: Network error_**.  Other functions still work fine - this only appears to affect adding answer units.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking into your issue it appears your Bluemix organization has multiple service instances.  The 403 issue you were seeing is because you're trying to access a Solr cluster using credentials from one of your instances against a cluster in the other instance.  The *1d111267-76b7-417a-98bd-4e9a58072ef9* represents one of these service instances—but the issue is that the cluster you're trying to access is not part of that instance.  A good way to test this is to ensure you're using the same credentials that generate the 403 but simply try to list the Solr clusters you have created by doing a GET against *https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/retrieve-and-rank/api/v1/solr_clusters/*.

As for the 500 issue, I wasn't able to see anything on our end.  If you're still experiencing that I would suggest posting another question and we can look into things again.

Thanks, 
-Scott